# Why does the fill of the clone turtle affects the original turtle fill?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Sry for being quite amateur at write this problem. This is my first time writing one.

I was doing some python turtle exercise for my assignment till I encounter this problem when filling up the Chinese character that I tried creating.
[image]

I tried to fill everything outline with black, but I keep on getting this weird white spot. I dunno understand how this happen

Here is the code that I used.(Quite amateur but I not sure how to improve). You can ignore most of the code except the final few codes relating to the clone. Feel free to add comment on how I can improve this
`

```
import turtle 
import importlib
importlib.reload(turtle)

screen = turtle.Screen()
turtletop = turtle.Turtle()
turtleright = turtle.Turtle()
turtleleft = turtle.Turtle()
turtles = [turtletop,turtleright,turtleleft] #all the turtle
turtlesbot = [turtleright,turtleleft] #bot turtle
for T in turtles:
    T.penup()
    T.pensize(1)
```

```
#putting all the turtle to different places
turtletop.goto(-68.5,66)
turtleright.goto(-57,-66)
turtleleft.goto(5,-66)

#putting all the turtle pen down 

for T in turtles: 
    T.pendown()
```

```
#Start filling the top part of the character 
turtletop.begin_fill() 
for i in range(4): 
    if(i%2==0): 
        turtletop.forward(140) 
    else: 
        turtletop.forward(15) 
    turtletop.left(90) 
turtletop.end_fill()
```

## drawing the bottom part of the character

```
for T in turtlesbot:
    T.color('black','black') 
    T.begin_fill() 
    T.left(90) 
    T.begin_fill() 
    for i in range(3): 
        if(i!=1): 
            if(i!=2): 
                T.forward(120) 
            else: 
                T.forward(105) 
                break 
        else:
            T.forward(55) 
            T.right(90)

T.circle(-15,90)
T.forward(15)
T.right(90)
T.forward(15)
T.right(90)
T.forward(15)
T.left(90)
for i in range(3):
    if(i ==0):
        T.forward(90)
    if(i==1):
        T.forward(25)
    if(i==2):
        T.forward(20)
        Tsquare = T.clone()
        T.forward(85)
        break
    T.left(90)
T.right(90)
T.forward(15)
T.end_fill()

#finish with drawing the two side character



#The clone that was place to finish of the character 
Tsquare.left(110)
for i in range(4):
    if(i%2==0):
        Tsquare.forward(13)
    else:
        Tsquare.forward(45)
    Tsquare.right(90)

Tsquare.end_fill()
```

`

I not sure how to fix this fill and I tried to change the fill color of the clone turtle but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your primary issue as two-fold, first your `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` calls don't match:

```
turtletop.begin_fill() 
turtletop.end_fill()
    T.begin_fill() 
    T.begin_fill() 
T.end_fill()
Tsquare.end_fill()
```

They should occur in matching pairs.  (OK, they sorta do when you account for cloning, but:)

Second, you `clone()` the turtle while it is in the middle of a `begin_fill()`, before the `end_fill()`.  So the turtle's state is still in filling mode when you go to use it -- this is what messes up the drawing.  It's still working with what it's already drawn.  But we don't need a clone in this situation, we just need to remember our position and heading.  Below is my rework of your code with these, and many other, changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle_top = Turtle()
turtle_top.penup()
turtle_top.pensize(1)

turtle_right = turtle_top.clone()
turtle_left = turtle_top.clone()

turtles = [turtle_top, turtle_right, turtle_left]  # all the turtles
bottom_turtles = [turtle_left, turtle_right]  # all bottom turtles

# Send all the turtles to different places
turtle_top.goto(-68.5, 66)
turtle_left.goto(-57, 52)
turtle_right.goto(5, 52)

# Put all the turtles pen down
for turtle in turtles:
    turtle.pendown()

# Start filling the top part of the character
turtle_top.begin_fill()

for _ in range(2):
    turtle_top.forward(140)
    turtle_top.left(90)
    turtle_top.forward(15)
    turtle_top.left(90)

turtle_top.end_fill()

# Draw the bottom part of the character

for turtle in bottom_turtles:
    turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.forward(55)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(105)

    turtle.circle(-15, 90)

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(15)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(15)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(25)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)

    position = turtle.position()
    heading = turtle.heading()

    turtle.forward(85)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(15)

    turtle.end_fill()

    # Finish with drawing the side characters

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(position)
    turtle.setheading(heading)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.left(110)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(13)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(45)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

for turtle in turtles:
    turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

I believe the reason you got color changes is related to the problem of filling five pointed stars, where on some systems you get a black star and others produce a black and white star.  The result of crossing of lines during a fill operation is system implementation specific.